# Activity freezes on setting image as a background using WallpaperManager

Tags: android

I'm setting image as a background using WallpaperManager but during setting whole activity freezes for a moment. I can see that because my progress bar spinner stops spinning.

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Is there a way to set image as a background without freezing whole activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it in a different thread to keep your activity from freezing.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do stuff here
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

hope it helps.